# Git - Rename multiple branches

Tags: git, bash

Here we have a git repo which has multiple branches which start with the same prefix just like this:

```
pfx.branchName1  
pfx.branchName2  
pfx.branchName3  
...
```

So the question is how to quickly remove all the prefixes ("pfx.") from all the branches and get something like this:

```
branchName1  
branchName2  
branchName3  
...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found an universal command that searches for the branches which contain our desired string (e.g. `"StringToFind"`) and renames by replacing that part with the string we want (e.g. `"ReplaceWith"`):

```
git branch | grep "StringToFind" | awk '{original=$1; sub("StringToFind","ReplaceWith"); print original, $1}' | xargs -n 2 git branch -m
```

**Note:** Before starting renaming we can run this command to see which branches are going to be renamed (just for convenience):

```
git branch | grep "StringToFind" | awk '{original=$1; sub("StringToFind","ReplaceWith"); print original, "->" , $1}'
```

So, for **our case**, use this for removing prefix:

```
git branch | grep "pfx." | awk '{original=$1; sub("pfx.",""); print original, $1}' | xargs -n 2 git branch -m
```

And this, for checking before removing:

```
git branch | grep "pfx." | awk '{original=$1; sub("pfx.",""); print original, "->", $1}'
```

Comment: The command I gave you is "universal" too, and safer: matching the prefix at the start of a branch name, and safe even with special characters in the branch name, running fewer processes, and simpler.

Comment: Btw, if you want to check before removing, a much easier way is to insert an `echo` right before the `git` command, for example `xargs -n 2 echo git branch -m`

Comment: this is good for local git branches. Is there a way to do it for origin branches too?

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the branch names from the output of `git branch`,
and then use a Bash loop with substitution to perform the renames:

```
git branch | sed -e 's/..//' | grep '^pfx\.' | while read b; do git branch -m "$b" "${b#pfx.}"; done
```

Or slightly more compactly but perhaps harder to read:

```
git branch | sed -ne 's/^..pfx\.//p' | while read b; do git branch -m "pfx.$b" "$b"; done
```

Comment: By omitting the `grep '^pfx\.'`, the second approach is assuming that all branches start with `pfx`, isn't it?

Comment: @JoaoDelgado thanks for spotting that, I forgot to add a `p` flag for the `s///` command, fixed now. (Without that flag, in fact nothing would be printed from `sed`, and so nothing renamed.)